# Производительность long-polling

Tags: производительность, long-poll

Если организовать long-polling через [EventSource](http://learn.javascript.ru/server-sent-events) и сервера на node.js например (на самом деле любая реализация), что будет с производительностью и потреблением ресурсов при большой нагрузке? Например, 1000000 подключений - получается 1000000 перманентных соединений. Не будет ли производительнее решение с отправкой запросов по тайм-ауту каждые 3 секунды?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, не будет, т.к. установка соединения - жирная операция (вы же можете в EventSource передать не одно событие), то что будет потребляться на сервере - память (1М на вес объекта соединения), но - если у вас есть 1М одновременных соединений, то у вас уже есть приличный доход, как минимум достаточный чтобы купить ещё памяти, кроме того, вы можете исхитриться и использовать несколько серверов. В случае миллиона запросов, каждые 3 секунды, вы будете в пике потреблять сеть (более дорогой ресурс) и проц (тоже не из дешевых). Причем звезды могут так сойтись, что к вам на сервер будут ломиться 100тыс в течении одной миллисекунды... а это уже совсем другой уровень. Но вообще, я бы не советовал вам eventSource - используйте вебсокеты, это проще.

Comment: почему не советуете EventSource - можно подробнее? вебсокеты - насчет них вроде еще даже производители не пришли к единому стандарту.

Comment: с eventSource - много возни, а толку мало, насчет стандарта - статус у eventSource не меньший драфт, чем у вебсокетов :)  Лучше просто на обоих сторонах заворачивать в socket.io, тогда апи у вас в зависимости от капризов w3c и вендоров меняться не будет (кроме того, клиентская реализация будет работать, даже если вебсокетов не будет поддержки вовсе), вообще для меня SSE выглядит странным костылем, чтобы поддерживать event pushing на php подобном коде. Это, конечно, хорошо, если не считать, что прогать асинхронное приложение на php слегка неудобно.

Comment: вот тут менее фанатичное, чем у меня сравнение. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195452/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-eventsource свои аргументы я высказал :)

Comment: боюсь, что нода ещё не скоро выдержит 1М параллельных подключений. уже при 10к на большинстве языков/платформ начинаются проблемы.

Comment: @KoVadim пруф плз.

Comment: Чтобы держать одно подключение, нужен один сокет (логично). На одном айпи открыть больше 64*1024 сокетов нельзя (особенности реализации сокетов). Поэтому больше 65536 сокетов на одном айпи работать не будет. По факту их сильно меньше. Опытные админы и хорошо написанный софт позволяют делать 30к одновременных подключений.  
Гуглите "c10k problem".

Заметьте, я говорю о "одновременных подключениях". Если количество обслуживаемых клиентов в секунду, то оно вообще-то может быть в районе миллиона, но при этом нужно, чтобы одного клиента за 30 мс обслужить.

Comment: вы про исходящие сокеты, а входящих можно открывать, пока память не кончится

http://stackoverflow.com/a/2332756/815386

Comment: Т.о. для создания нагрузки в 1М соединений на сервер (1 порт) нужно иметь как минимум 16 клиентских хостов (IP интерфейсов).

Comment: 16 - это сильно завышенная оценка. На моей практике я участвовал в паре высоконагруженных проектов и как раз упирались в 30к. Добавление ещё одного айпишника сразу подымало в два раза. Другими средствами не удавалось. Оба проекта были на java, возможно, в этом дело (но я сомневаюсь).

Comment: @KoVadim, Вы упирались в accept возвращает -1 при 30K?

Comment: я не могу ответить на этот вопрос. Во первых, в java редко кто пишет прямо вызов accept, а используются библиотеки (например, netty), а во вторых, докупить ip оказалось сильно дешевым решением, которое устроило всех.